# PostgresSQL date/time field out of range on seconds-since-epoch

Tags: postgresql, datetime, postgresql-9.5, timestamp

I am importing a csv file into a PostgreSQL database. Most of the file imports without any trouble until I get this message

```
ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: "1421088300"
HINT:  Perhaps you need a different "datestyle" setting.
CONTEXT:  COPY accidents, line 6356158, column datetime: "1421088300"
```

But this seems to be a valid timestamp for 01/12/2015 @ 6:45pm (UTC) according to https://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php

So why is it out of range?

Comment: This is a timestamp in a particular sense of the word.  However, it looks like a string literal with the quotes.  You might need an intermediate table to import the data into, which accepts `text`, and then convert it to a proper timestamp.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37342829

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Seconds since epoch timestamps

Your "timestamp" is in seconds-since-epoch. Per dezso, use `to_timestamp()`. I missed that when I checked `\dfS+`

## Bad complex idea, and dragons.

Check [the input formats](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html#datatype-datetime-input). They cover casts from strings. That's what `COPY` is doing under the hood. The only method that even remotely looks like a long number is ISO 8601. If you look at that example though you'll see it's not a seconds-since-epoch

```
Example    | Description
19990108   | ISO 8601; January 8, 1999 in any mode
```

This is basically the same as another example on that chart.

```
Example    | Description
1999-01-08 | ISO 8601; January 8, 1999 in any mode
```

### Converting to `timestamp` with `abstime` as an intermediary format

So if you want to convert from seconds-since-epoch, you can cheat by using the internal `abstime` since there is no available cast directly to timestamp from a string of seconds-since-epoch.

```
SELECT 1421088300::abstime::timestamp;
      timestamp      
---------------------
 2015-01-12 12:45:00
(1 row)
```

What's happening here is that `abstime` is binary coercable with `integer`. You can see that in `\dC+`. I checked `\dfS+` for functions to get from integer to timestamp and found none. There is a cast though from integer to `abstime` (which is stored as an integer), and from `abstime` to `timestamp`.

If this is a new table you could actually type that column as `abstime`. It should load perfectly fine. And then you can `ALTER TABLE`. here is an example, except I'm not running `COPY` (but it should work all the same).

```
CREATE TABLE foo(bar)
AS VALUES
  (1421088300::abstime);

TABLE foo;
          bar           
------------------------
 2015-01-12 12:45:00-06
(1 row)

ALTER TABLE foo
  ALTER bar
  TYPE timestamp;

TABLE foo;
         bar         
---------------------
 2015-01-12 12:45:00
(1 row)

\d foo;
                Table "public.foo"
 Column |            Type             | Modifiers 
--------+-----------------------------+-----------
 bar    | timestamp without time zone |
```